# If ifconfig is not installed, how does ubuntu tell you to install net-tools in order to use ifconfig? Why doesn't Debian do this?

Tags: command-line, networking, apt, bash, debian

If (as an example) `net-tools` package is not installed and I try to use `ifconfig` command, Ubuntu says

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install net-tools
```

How can Ubuntu (unlike e.g. Debian) know which package I need to install to use that command?

Comment: Why or why not Debian does X, Y and Z is a good question for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ but not really a topic here.

Comment: are you sure https://packages.debian.org/unstable/command-not-found as it is part of Debian.

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67473/10017 This might still be the case.

Answer (score 2):

> How does Ubuntu know which package I need to install to use that command?

The package that does this is actually called [command-not-found](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=command-not-found) and it uses a cache to gather all the commands installed (`update-command-not-found` does this).